# SQL to show all customers and the items they have purchased without lots of joins

Tags: sql

I would like to write a query that prints a result set whose rows are customers and the columns are the items with a 'Y' or 'N' in each field depending on whether the customer has purchased that item.

In short, I have the following tables:

| CustomerID | CustomerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe Bloggs |
| 2 | Jane Doe |
| 3 | John Smith |

| ItemID | ItemName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | knife |
| 2 | fork |
| 3 | spoon |

| PurchaseID | CustomerID | ItemID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |

I would like to write a query that gives the following result:

| Customer | Knife | Fork | Spoon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe Bloggs | Y | N | N |
| Jane Doe | Y | Y | N |
| John Smith | N | N | Y |

I have written the following query which does the job

```
SELECT CustomerName, [appropriate case statements for the 'Y' and 'N']
FROM ct
LEFT JOIN pt AS pt1 ON ct.customerID = pt1.customerID
LEFT JOIN pt AS pt2 ON ct.customerID = pt2.customerID
LEFT JOIN pt AS pt3 ON ct.customerID = pt3.customerID
WHERE pt1.itemID = 1 AND pt2.itemID = 2 AND pt3.itemID = 3
```

The idea here is that I have to join another copy of the purchase table for each item. With a lot of items, this becomes extremely computationally costly.

I am wondering if there is any way I can get the same result without having to do a join for every item. Is there a way to do it with just one join? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: "With a lot of items, this becomes extremely computationally costly." - Use the index Luke!  (I've been waiting a long time to say that!)  https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    c.CustomerName AS Customer,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN i.ItemName = 'knife' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Knife,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN i.ItemName = 'fork'  THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Fork,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN i.ItemName = 'spoon' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Spoon
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN CustomerItem ci
    ON ci.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Items i
    ON i.ItemID = ci.ItemID
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerName;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you. I used this idea to do even more than I had hoped by using a group_concat(CASE WHEN [product name].... ELSE NULL) to put the order status and date instead of just Y/N. Thanks!